# How to hide end of a video in a div box with overflow: hidden?

Tags: html, css

I want to hide the ends of a video >(greater in size) div-box like with an image using overflow: hidden (and without losing the proportion of the video). The codes I used:

**CSS3**

```
#cookVideo { /*Video Box*/
display: inline;
position: relative;
background-clip:border-box;
float: left;
z-index: 2;
min-width: 50%;
max-width: 50%;
min-height: 400px;
height: 400px;
width: 50%;
margin-top: -8px;
padding: 0px;
}

#dynamic {/* Container - Zoom Image and Cooking   Video*/

position: relative;
top: 0px;
margin-left: -11px;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 382px;
overflow: hidden;
/*border: 1px solid green;*/
}
```

**HTML PART**

```
<section id="midContainer">
  <article>
    <header id="dynamic">
       <video id="cookVideo" autoplay loop>
             <source src="css/images/Shrimpsmall.mp4">
       </video>
   </header>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: www.foodcakey.xyz help please help

Comment: What do you mean by `hide the ends of a video`? Do you mean *put an overlay (like a TV chassis) over top of the video element so that the edges of the video element are hidden underneath the overlay?*

Comment: yes, i want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to use a plugin if you want it to be responsive or to use percentages. Here is an example using [Vide](http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/)

The video is wrapped in another div and when the plugin is called, it stretches the video to cover the wrapper kind of like how background-size:cover works.

```js
$('#cookVideo').vide();
```

```css
#dynamic {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left: -11px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 382px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* border: 1px solid green; */
}


#cookVideo-wrapper {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    background-clip: border-box;
    float: left;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 400px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
    padding: 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}


#zoomImage {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: url("http://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/foodncake/css/images/Choco.jpg") center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: content-box;
    height: 400px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/js/jquery.vide.min.js"></script>

     <header id="dynamic">
       <div id="zoomImage"> </div>
       <div id="cookVideo-wrapper">
          <video id="cookVideo" autoplay="" loop="">
            <source src="http://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/foodncake/css/images/Shrimpsmall.mp4">          
          </video>
        </div>
      </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually, here are the points:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/cd99bvcL/)</kbd>

(1) Header (`#dynamic`) is an outer container div, styled as `position:relative`. *This is necessary because the inner DIVs cannot be styled `position:absolute` unless their parent div is styled either `absolute` or `relative`*

(2) Both `#cookvideo` and `#olay` (overlay) are inside the header, and are styled `position:absolute`.

(3) The overlay DIV should have `background-color:transparent` and use a thick border for the frame, *OR* use a background-image (png with a transparent middle) as a more sophisticated frame.

(4) It might be tricky to correctly position the frame because the browser stylesheets (part of each browser, not standard across browsers) do some basic styling to a `video` element. You may have to over-ride that default styling.